# non-blocking assignments with if statements

Tags: verilog, fpga

A bit confused about how Verilog interprets this code block and how it is synthesized in FPGA.

```
...
data_reg[bit_count] <= rx;
bit_count <= bit_count + 1;
if (bit_count == 7) begin
    bit_count <= 0;
end
...
```

The question is: if bit_count == 7 does data_reg[7] == rx or may bit_count change before data_reg[bit_count] gets assigned resulting in data_reg[0] == rx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is sequential logic (`always @(posedge clk)...`) Then `bit_count` is its *old* or *current* value. So if it's current value is 7, the assignment will be made to 8, but then it will be overridden to 0. The select on the LHS of `data_reg[bit_count]` uses the *old* value of `bit_select`.

If this is combinational logic, you should not be using NBAs to variables within the block.